# How to authenticate from program code to retrieve data from specific uri in android..?

Tags: java, android, html, httprequest, authenticator

I am working on project in which i need to by pass authentication through coding and hit a Uri to fetch some data.

like the uri for Login page is:

```
 http://www.test.com/login.htm
```

where two TextFields are provided for username and password.on click of submit i am lead to the page having uri:

```
http://www.test.com/status/info.htm
```

where the needed information is provided in the form of html data.

Now i `want to hit info page directly on click of button` by passing the Login page.

Since i Know the UserName and password..

I have tried Authenticator as shown:

```
 Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator(){
 protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() { 
    return new PasswordAuthentication("admin","admin".toCharArray());
 }});
```

But didn't worked..

I have even tried setting Header as

```
httpGet.setHeader("Authorization","Basic "+ Base64.encodeToString("admin:admin".getBytes(),
                                        Base64.NO_WRAP));
```

But it didnt worked as well..

Kindly provide an appropriate Solution.../

Comment: More than likely, the authentication happens through a POST with session cookies. Run the site in Chrome with Developer Tools enabled and watch the Network tab.

Comment: @323go i am not doing this on browser but Activity of in android..

Comment: He is suggesting this only for figuring out how to do it, Amritpal.